# find smallest $x>0$ such that $\frac{A}{cx}e^{-cx^2}\le \varepsilon$

Tags: analysis, inequality

I was estimating some error and I got

$$\varepsilon(x)\le\frac{A}{cx}e^{-cx^2}$$

$A,c$ are known and positive, $x$ is also positive.

The bigger the $x$ smaller the error. 
But I need to find the smallest possible $x$ such that $\,\varepsilon(x)\le \varepsilon$, lets say $\varepsilon = 10^{-5} $.

To be specific, I need

$$ \inf_{x\in A}A=\left\{ \ x>0\ \ \Big\rvert \ \  \frac{A}{cx}\, e^{-cx^2}\le \varepsilon \ \right\}.$$

It does not need to be exactly infimum but try to get as close as you can.

Comment: The infimum will always be $0$. Can you rephrase your question? Which parametrs do you want to tune?

Comment: Just a thought... if $0<x<1$ you may be able to expand $Ae^{-cx^2}\leq cx\varepsilon,$ and use $-Acx^2-cx\varepsilon\leq O(x^4)$...

Comment: You can solve $\frac{A}{cx}e^{-cx^2}= \varepsilon$ in terms of the Lambert W function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raise to the $-2$ power:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\varepsilon^2}
&\le\left(\frac{A}{cx}e^{-cx^2}\right)^{-2}\\
&=\frac{c}{2A^2}2cx^2e^{2cx^2}\\
\frac{2A^2}{c\varepsilon^2}
&\le2cx^2e^{2cx^2}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\operatorname{W}\left(\frac{2A^2}{c\varepsilon^2}\right)\le2cx^2
$$
Therefore, the smallest $x$ would be
$$
\sqrt{\frac1{2c}\operatorname{W}\left(\frac{2A^2}{c\varepsilon^2}\right)}
$$
where $\operatorname{W}$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

---

For $x\ge1$, $xe^x\ge e^x$. Therefore, $x\ge\operatorname{W}(e^x)$. Thus, for $x\ge e$, $\log(x)\ge\operatorname{W}(x)$.

Therefore, if $\varepsilon\le A\sqrt{\frac2{ce}}$, then
$$
x=\sqrt{\frac1{2c}\log\left(\frac{2A^2}{c\varepsilon^2}\right)}
$$
is a decent overestimate for the $x$ necessary.

Comment: thanks i saw that function when i was searching online, but i need some solution in terms of "normal"  functions ( like log, exp , sin , cos ...) . I didn't want to write this right away but this what one author gives as estimate for x  is $x \sim \sqrt{\frac{1}{c} \log{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}}$

Comment: Your given estimate cannot be correct, because it does not include $A$. But if the argument of $W(x)$ is large (as would be expected if $\varepsilon$ is small) you can use $W(x) \sim \ln(x)$

Comment: thats awesome, how can i show that $W(x)\sim ln(x)$ for large x

Comment: This is the first term of 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions,
a proof can be found in the first reference,  Corless et al http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/W-adv-cm.pdf

Comment: @jack: I show in my answer, right below the horizontal line, that for $x\ge e$, $\log(x)\ge\operatorname{W}(x)$.

Comment: @robjohn i added how i got $log(x)\ge W(x)$ it disapeared or something, but how do you get it from $x \ge W(e^x)$, it is true i checked but it is not clear to me from the answer

Comment: @jack: you tried to edit the post, and it was denied. Your edit should have been a comment. In any case, once you have $x\ge\operatorname{W}(e^x)$, just substitute $x\mapsto\log(x)$ and you get $\log(x)\ge\operatorname{W}(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

A handy fact for this kind of problem is that
$$ f(x) = x\ln x \quad\text{and}\quad g(x) = \frac{x}{\ln x} $$
are approximately inverses, in the sense that
$$ f(g(x)) = x(1-o(1)) \quad\text{and}\quad g(f(x)) = x(1-o(1)) $$
(as $x\to\infty$).

Squaring your desired inequality and setting $u=2cx^2$, it becomes equivalent to
$$ \ln\frac{2A^2}{c\varepsilon^2} \le u\ln u $$
Applying $g$ to both sides gives that
$$ \frac{\ln\frac{2A^2}{c\epsilon^2}}{\ln\ln\frac{2A^2}{c\varepsilon^2}} \le u $$
is approximately equivalent.  If you're not too picky, at this point you might simplify by saying that $\ln\frac{2A^2}{c\varepsilon^2}\le u$ would suffice; returning to $x$ will give an estimate similar to the one you gave in the comments.

(If you *are* too picky to throw away the denominator there, then I think you'll also need to be more precise about the $o(1)$ in the equations for $f$ and $g$.)

Comment: thanks , sorry that i cant accept both answers :(

Comment: You can accept one amd upvote the other.